# Add a curly brace to the first and last line of a text file using Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm parsing and formatting a text file using the Node File System module which is then output into a newly formatted text file.  How can I add a { to the first line of text file and a } to the last line of the text file while retaining the formatting?

I tried using array.unshift("{\n"); and array.push("}"); to add curly braces to the file but the console throws "array.unshift is not a function".

```
const fs = require('fs');

const array = fs.readFileSync('input.txt').toString().split("\n");

let result = '';

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
    result += ( "\t\"" + (i + 1) + "\" : [ \"" + array[i] + "\" ], \n");
};

result.unshift("{\n");
result.push("}");

fs.writeFile("output.txt", result, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
});
```

I expect output.text to read:

```
{
    "1" : [ "car" ],
    "2" : [ "train"],
}
```

but the actual output is "result.unshift is not a function".

Comment: `unshift` and `push` are array methods — you have a string. Just start with `let result = '{';` and at the end contact the last character `result += '}'`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of what you are doing manually trying to create json (which is error prone), create an actual object using a simple `Array#reduce()` then `JSON.stringify()` that  whole object to write to file

```
const array = fs.readFileSync('input.txt').toString().split("\n");

const res = array.reduce((a, c, i) => (a[i]=[c], a), {});

const jsonString = JSON.stringify( res, null, '\t');

fs.writeFile("output.txt", jsonString  , function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `result` is not an array, its a string. Strings do neither have an `.unshift` nor a `.push` method. To add characters at the beginning do:

```
 result = "{" + result;
```

... but why don't you just set `result` to that *before looping*?

```
let result = '{';
```